# ThreeJs OrbitControls: How can I disable mouse pan without disabling keys pan?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to disable users from panning with their mouse, but to still be allowed to pan with the keys. If is use `controls.enablePan = false;`, I cannot use the keys to pan. However, if I try to rebind the mouse buttons, it forces me to assign a mouse button to Orbit, Pan and Zoom. How can I disable the users from using the mouse pan, but still be able to pan with the keys? I don't want to completely disable the mouse because I need to be able to orbit with the right mouse button.

Comment: try set CSS ```pointer-events: none;``` It will 
disable mouse events, while having keyboard events handled. Refer https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/pointer-events/

Comment: @AlexKhoroshylov Thanks for the reply, but I still need to use the right mouse button to orbit. Wouldn't this completely disable mouse events?

Comment: it will disable all mouse events, true

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to disable just mouse pan. You'll need to download and modify [OrbitControls.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) and comment out, delete, or modify the code related to panning with the mouse.

For example this line

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/bcd4bec92609ce8af76a590b0f281ecf71019c2b/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L703

and this line

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/bcd4bec92609ce8af76a590b0f281ecf71019c2b/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js#L780

etc...

Comment: I never thought about editing the source code. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried changing the [mouse buttons](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.mouseButtons) property?

Something like that:

```
controls.mouseButtons = {
    LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY,
    RIGHT: ''
}
```

It solved a similar issue that I had some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign the control keys, effectively disabling them:

```
this.controls.keys = { LEFT: 0, RIGHT: 0, UP: 0, BOTTOM: 0 }
```